# Bootable USB image

Tags: 12.10, usb, live-usb, clonezilla

I have read and tried a number of the scenarios in the Clonezilla live docs and I haven't as yet been successful in creating what I hope I can. I have also searched the Forum here (via key words etc) for possibly similar scenarios and again, have not been successful.

I built an Ubuntu installation with one Java based app and TrueCrypt on the HD of my laptop. Using Gparted, I shrank the partitions for Ubuntu and TrueCrypt to 8gb and 4gb respectively.

I have a non-U3 16gb USB drive that I would like to transfer the two partitions onto in such a way that I can boot directly off the USB drive. Ideally, I wouldn't have to re-create the TrueCrpt partition but if I did, that wouldn't be a show stopper.

I used CloneZilla to create an image of the two partitions and save it to a third partition (sda4).

Can someone please point me in the right direction to instructions that will allow me to create a bootable USB version of the two partitions on the HD?

I've tried part image to part image
disk to disk (USB too small)
Basic mode
Advanced Mode

Help, please? If CloneZilla is not the right tool, please let me know what is.

Any and all assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it by creating a bootable LiveUSB install of Ubuntu with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) with 4GB of RAM preserved for Persistance (i.e., you can save stuff to the flashdrive). Once that's groovy, then Clonezilla should allow you to recover the TrueCrypt partition to the unused space on the USB flashdrive.